# OpenMP first kernel much slower than the second kernel

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I have a huge 98306 by 98306 2D array initialized. I created a kernel function that counts the total number of elements below a certain threshold.

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:num_below_threshold)
for(row)
    for(col)
        index = get_corresponding_index(row, col);
        if (array[index] < threshold)
            num_below_threshold++;
```

For benchmark purpose I measured the execution time of the kernel executing when the number of thread is set to 1. I noticed that the first time the kernel executes it took around 11 seconds. The next call to the kernel executing on the same array with one thread only took around 3 seconds. I thought it might be a problem related to cache but it doesn't seem to be related. What is the possible reasons that caused this?

This array is initialized as:

```
float *array = malloc(sizeof(float) * 98306 * 98306);
for (int i = 0; i < 98306 * 98306; i++) {
    array[i] = rand() % 10;
}
```

This same kernel is applied to this array twice and the second execution time is much faster than the first kernel. I though of lazy allocation on Linux but that shouldn't be a problem because of the initialization function. Any explanations will be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Post a [MCVE]. In particular, *how* did you initialize the array?

Comment: @EOF I added the example. But I didn't see how exactly the way the array is initialized affects the execution results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you don't provide any [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I'll have to make some wild guesses here, but I'm pretty confident I have the gist of the issue.

First, you have to notice that 98,306 x 98,306 is 9,664,069,636 which is way larger than the maximum value a signed 32 bit integer can store (which is 2,147,483,647). Therefore, the upper limit of your `for` initialization loop, after overflowing, could become 1,074,135,044 (as on my machines, although it is undefined behavior so strictly speaking, anything could happen), which is roughly 9 times smaller than what you expected.

So now, after the initialization loop, only 11% of the memory you thought you allocated has actually been allocated and touched by the operating system. However, your first reduction loop does a good job in going over the various elements of the array, and since for about 89% of it, it's for the fist time, the OS does the actual memory allocation there and then, which takes some significant amount of time.

And now, for your second reduction loop, all memory has been properly allocated and touched, which makes it much faster.

So that's what I believe happened. That said, many other parameters can enter into play here, such as:

- **Swapping**: the array you try to allocate represents about 36GB of memory. If your machine doesn't have that much memory available, then your code might swap, which will potentially make a big mess of whatever performance measurement you can come up with
- **NUMA effect**: if your machine has multiple NUMA nodes, then thread pinning and memory affinity, when not managed properly, can have a large impact on performance between loop occurrences
- **Compiler optimization**: you didn't mention which compiler you used and which level of optimization you requested. Depending on that, you'd be amazed on how shortened your code could become. For example, the compiler could totally remove the second loop as it does the same thing as the first and becomes useless as the result will be the same... And many other interesting and unexpected things which render your benchmark meaningless

Comment: The signed integer overflow is undefined behavior, so the compiler can remove the code entirely.

Comment: @EOF good point. I added a note mentioning it (although I'm still quite confident things are like I described them)

Comment: It appears compiler optimization is the reason why the problem occurs. For some reason the compiler decided to change the reduction operation into atomic add. That makes all the difference.